# url pattern in ajax call what does dot indicates?

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, spring, web-applications

I am new to Ajax. i have below code.

```
 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../myController",
        data: dataString,

    });
```

Basically this is not specific to Ajax question. it is java. i am not sure what does two dots `(..)` indicates in url ?

what does `..` or `.` indicates in url ?

Thanks!

Comment: it means "Up One Directory".

Comment: Could you plz point me to righ URL where i can find meaning of various expressions? like what various dots indicates? what is the meaning of single dot and double dot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is known as relative URL. ".." means parent directory and "." means current directory.

http://www.w3.org/Addressing/rfc1808.txt, Try searching relative URLs here.